# Run a django app inside a docker container

Tags: python, django, docker

I am running succesfully a django app that is hosted inside a docker container. I change something on my code on purpose in order for my code to break. What I need is somehow to see the log of the running code as if I was running this locally on my computer. For example I forgot to import a library and when I run this locally I get a message on the terminal like "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somemodule'". But when i run the same code from inside the container I get no log, just the container fails to start.

My question is: How can I get a log for my script from inside the container, so I can debug my code?

Comment: How do you start a container?

Comment: Do `docker ps -a` to find the name of the failed container. Then `docker logs <container name>` to see the output from your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I wanted to do was to somehow debug/run my own python code that was inside a container in order to see the log of my code.

I managed to do it using VSC and Remote SSH and Remote - Containers extensions.

[Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)

[Remote - Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

If the containers are hosted locally on your PC, you dont need the Remote - SSH extension